# How to safely rollback Primary Indexes in MySql Database using Laravel migrations

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I was using the Entrust roles and permission library for Laravel and Lumen. Although I had a reason to use it differently from the way it was supposed to be used because of my unique case. I needed to have multiple instances of of a user with the same role differentiated by a certain foreign key.

Lets assume I wanted a user to have same role for different jobs or different roles for different jobs so I added a job_id to the `role_users` table to help me filter the roles a user has for for a particular job..

This just means a user can be an admin for job1 and an admin for job2.. This posed a problem because Entrust some how made primary keys of both role_id and user_id on the role_users table..

First I didn't think that was possible, plus I don't understand why.. This also means that I couldn't have multiple instances of the same role_id and user_id which i wanted. I did a little research and found out I could drop a primary key using `$table->dropPrimary()` method.

I did this in my `up()` method, although the action needs to be replicated in my down method. I couldnt' create a primary key there because if multiple instances already exist it would thrown a fatal exception.

Basically I need a way to drop the primary key on condition that it exists so I don't have to recreate it in the down method.

Comment: Well.. format it to be not wall of text is the first step

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to put anything in `down()` in this case.

My usual rule for putting something in `down()` is when the `up()` contains something that will prevent my migration to rollback successfully.

In your case dropping a primary key won't affect the rollback in any way.

If you really need to have this rollback. You could add some script that handles duplicates in your table and apply the primary key again

Comment: The problem is if i rollback because of some reason and try to migrate again, there isn't a primary key for me to drop. Thats the problem

Comment: In that case, you need to create some kind of script that handles the duplicate rows in your table in `down()`. Either move them to a temporarily table or anything. Then apply back the Primary Key.